# Should I better modify some codes for .ClearContents?

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple macros for clearing cells on "Sheet1", which have drop down lists.

```
Sub reset1()

    Range("D20:E21").ClearContents
    Range("D8:E9").ClearContents
    Range("D6:E7").ClearContents

End Sub

Sub reset2()

    Range("D20:E21").ClearContents
    Range("D8:E9").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Then I call these macros on "Sheet1" if the cell values change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
        Call reset1
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$6" Then
        Call reset2
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is written on the "Sheet1".

Normally it works but sometimes reset1() doesn't work.

I should then save and reopen the excel or run the macro manually.

Should I better modify some codes?

Comment: Does Reset1 call Worksheet_Change to run reset2? as D6 is changing in reset1?

Comment: You should disable events while changing cells from a `Change` event.

Comment: I agree with @Rory. You may want to see this [Working with Worksheet Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that with `Range("D20:E21")` it is not clear in which worksheet that range should be. Always specify the worksheet like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:E21")`.

Second problem is that if you `.ClearContents` in a `Worksheet_Change` event this is a cell change and triggers another `Worksheet_Change` event and so on. So it is recommended to disable events `Application.EnableEvents = False` before changing cells in `Worksheet_Change` event.

Third problem is that if you test  `Target.Address = "$D$4"` and you copy paste a range where `D4` is included your code will not run even if your cell `D4` changed. Therefore you always need to work with `Intersect`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Reset1(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Range("D20:E21,D8:E9,D6:E7").ClearContents
    ' alternative:
    ' Union(ws.Range("D20:E21"), ws.Range("D8:E9"), ws.Range("D6:E7")).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub Reset2(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Range("D20:E21,D8:E9").ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS  ' in any case an error happens make sure events are enabeld again
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        Reset1 Me  ' here we tell Reset1 to take `Me` as worksheet. Me refers to the worksheet `Target` is in.
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D6")) Is Nothing Then
        Reset2 Me
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where should I put then the code to disable events?

Comment: @MienYi My fault, forget to use it :) See my edited answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will comment again if it doesn't work sometimes but for now looks perfect.